# MVC’s DefaultModelBinder does not Validate The Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, fluentvalidation

I'm using FluentValidation MVC5 for validating the object. I've followed this [tutorial](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation). When I post the form, why MVC DefaultModelBinder does not validate the object? FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider is already configured in global.asax

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
}
```

ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled is set true in web.config.
I've also downloaded latest jquery.validation package, add to BundleConfig, and in its view (Create.cshtml) I've added

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

CurrencyViewModel.cs

```
[Validator(typeof(CurrencyViewModelValidator))]
public class CurrencyViewModel
{
    public int CurrencyID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CurrencyViewModel>
{
    public CurrencyViewModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Code).Length(3);
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).Length(3, 50);
    }
}
```

CurrencyController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(CurrencyViewModel currencyVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Currency currency = new Currency()
        {
            Code = currencyVM.Code,
            Name = currencyVM.Name
        };

        db.Currencies.Add(currency);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(currencyVM);
}
```

Comment: In VS put breakpoint in if (ModelState.IsValid) line and then check values in model to see what's causing errors.

Comment: @NareshRavlani The values in currency are null, but ModelState.IsValid is true, weird. It should not reach ModelState.IsValid if client-side validation is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The values in currency are null, but ModelState.IsValid is true, weird.

This is completely normal behavior. The validator checks for a string length, not whether a property is null. [Documentation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Validators&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#Length):

> Ensures that the length of a particular string property is within the specified range.

If you do not want to allow null values you should use [NotNull](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Validators&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#NotNull) validator:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Code).NotNull().Length(3);
RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().Length(3, 50);
```

Comment: Solved, thanks @Zabavsky, I'm not aware about null value

Comment: May I ask you another question? Before using FluentValidation, I'm using DataAnnotation for validation at CurrencyMetaData class. So, could I delete CurrencyMetaData class, as it is no longer use, or is there any other functional beside validation?

Comment: Your metadata class can contain additional annotation attributes besides validation like `DisplayAttribute`, `DataTypeAttribute` etc., but for validation you have to use either `DataAnnotation` or `FluentValidation`.